# What's the requirement on GPX file format from DDMS?

Tags: android, ddms, gpx

I'm now working on android platform and developing app using location information. However, I cannot get DDMS to recognize my gpx file. I know that many people are having similar problems, and someone suggests the website http://ge2adt.appspot.com/ is helpful.

Unfortunately I cannot access this site in China because of GFW. What I need is the detailed requirement from DDMS on gpx format. A working sample file is also quite helpful.

Comment: Please check this question. It seems that DDMS only supports 1.1 GPX files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231274

Answer (score 1):

GPX files must be in 1.1 format apparently. I couldn't find any documentation to confirm that, however it seems to be the case as commented [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2528#c5) and also in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231274).